# odoo make field readonly when not empty

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10, odoo-9

I have this field

```
<field name="date" />
```

and

`date = fields.Date('Order Date')`

How to make it readonly and can not be edited when there is value in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```xml
<field name="date" attrs="{'readonly': [('date', '!=', False)]}" />
```

That should be enough.

Comment: now there is an error: uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setting' of unfefined

Comment: what does "now" mean? If you changed something after it already worked, you may have made another mistake?

Comment: I don't really sure what I've done. But now there is an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined when I use attrs="{'readonly': [('date', '!=', False)]}"

Comment: What did you change?